# Struggle with derivation

Tags: partial-derivative

I have $\Omega$ the following domain 
$$
\Omega = \left\{\left(x_1,x_2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ 1 \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \leq 2\right\} \text{ and }u\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)
$$

I'm asked to calculate $\displaystyle \frac{ \partial u }{\partial n}$ on $\Gamma$.

I guess $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $\Omega$ but I dont know what is $n$ and i've no idea how to calculate this.
I know how to calculate derivative relatively to $x_1$ or $x_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for a differentiable function the directional derivative is given by

$$\frac{ \partial u }{\partial n}=\nabla u \cdot n$$

where, in that case if we refer to the boundary, $n$ is the unit normal vectors to the circle centered at the origin that is for $P=(x,y)$

$$n=\pm \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)$$

and

$$\nabla u=(u_x,u_y)=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Comment: I've to admit that I dont understand the formula ( I understand nabla etc but how can from what it stems ? )

Comment: @Atmos It is just a generalization of partial derivative. For a differentiable function, in a generic direction $n$ the directional derivative is given by the dot product of the gradient vector  and the vector $n$.

Comment: @Atmos Refer also to the [Related OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583839/505767)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gimusi

Comment: @Atmos I need to fix something on n!

Comment: @Atmos Now it should be ok, indeed of course n depends upon x and y! Let me know for any other doubts on that! Bye

Comment: is this $f$ or $\nabla u$ ? :p

Comment: @Atmos Yes of course, I change the synmol according to your one!

Comment: Last question : if i find that such a derivative is null what can i conclude ?

Comment: @Atmos Nothing special, but for that particular function it is never true. Indeed the function in any radial direction form the origin is $u(r)= \ln r$ with $1\le r \le \sqrt 2$ and $u'(r)=\frac1r$ which indeed is the same result we obtain by the directional derivative.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with an annulus and the function is radially symmetric, switch to polar coordinates.

The normal to your boundary is then just $r/|r|$ as you want to move orthogonally to the circle.