# Why do all directional derivatives in $0$ exist for $f(x)=\frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}, \quad x\neq 0 \\ 0 , \quad \quad \, \, \, \,  x=0\end {cases}$.

Show that all directional derivates in $0\in \mathbb{R}^2$ exist.

My attempt:

Let $a:=(0,0)$ and $v:=(x,y)$ with $x\neq y$, then:$$\partial _v f(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+t(x,y))-f(0)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(xt,yt)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{(xt)^2(yt)}{(xt)^2+(yt)^2}}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{t^3x^2y}{t^3(x^2+y^2)}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ But that is just valid iff $x\neq y$. Do I have to show $x=y$ seperately?

Comment: Where did you use $x\ne y$?

Comment: Oh god, I get it know! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation is fine, for $x=y=c$ we obtain

$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac12c$$

what we need is $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Note also that usually we assume $|(x,y)|=1$ and in this case we have

$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}x^2y$$

Refer also to the related

- [Directional Derivative(DD)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583839/505767)

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable in $0$?